# Understanding the referent of a pronoun in this sentence

Tags: sentence

The sentence is taken from clash of clan game tips screen.

> Pekka's armour is so heavy that the spring trap doesn't work on **her**.

Now, I would like to know, what is the referent for the highlighted part. What does `her` refer to - pekka or the armour?

From the name I am inclined to assume that pekka is a male warrior and the `her` refers to the armour, but I am not sure.

Comment: Help with tags please. I am new to this stackexchange sister site.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! **her** refers to _Pekka_, and I would assume it's a female name — but then, in my neck of the woods, most names that end in _-a_ are female. The question _is_ interesting, because the subject of the sentence appears to be _Pekka's armour_, not _Pekka_; semantically though, it doesn't seem to make sense to have _her_ refer to the armour, all the more since objects are _it_ in English, not _her_, unless the armour is somehow an animated thing.

Comment: Virtual gamespeak. http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/P.E.K.K.A

Comment: and according to that site, yes PEKKA is a she. So your answer is correct, oerkelens.

Answer (score 3):

*Her* refers to P.E.K.K.A., not the armor.

> Pekka's armour is so heavy that the spring trap doesn't work on her.

We can substitute parts of this sentence, and make something more logically intuitive in order to show that this sentence structure is acceptable.

First, I'll highlight the components we'll change.

> Pekka's [armour] is so [heavy] that [the spring trap doesn't work on her].

First we have the subject of the base clause, then an adjective modifying that subject, and then finally a secondary clause with a pronoun subject (that we will see is not necessarily the same as the original subject).

> Pekka's [SAT score] is so [low] that [community colleges reject her].

Clearly, Pekka, and not the score, is being rejected in this case. Of course, it isn't even necessary to have the pronoun's original noun in the same sentence.

> [It's raining so hard] that [I don't think he'll make it].

In this case, the subject is the first 'it', while the pronoun 'he' refers to a person that presumably both the speaker and audience have already identified.

Finally, one can make an illogical sentence of this construction without violating any rules of grammar.

> [This car is so heavy] that [Texas outlawed string bean exports].

The sentence declares a causative relationship between the car's weight and Texas' agricultural export policies. Illogical, and yet grammatical. There is no necessary connection between the clauses on either side of 'that' other than the *logical* connection created by the syntax itself.

Grammatically, "*Clause* that *clause*" will generally work for essentially any two arbitrary clauses.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: both. But the narrative really cares more about Pekke than the armor, so "she" is used rather than "it".

The sentence is, tecnnically, ungrammatical, but the meaning is clear (at least to a native speaker).